# Объясните внятно разницу между пользовательскими и системными абстракциями и приведите примеры

Tags: windows, терминология, ос

Читаю книгу про операционные системы, зашла тема до пользовательских и системных абстракций. Ввела меня в заблуждение следующая цитата из этой книги:

> Следует отметить, что реальными «заказчиками» операционных систем являются прикладные программы (разумеется, не без помощи прикладных программистов).
> Именно они непосредственно работают с операционной системой и ее абстракциями.
> А конечные пользователи работают с абстракциями, предоставленными пользовательским интерфейсом, — это или командная строка оболочки, или графический интерфейс. Абстракции пользовательского интерфейса могут быть похожими на абстракции, предоставляемые операционной системой, но так бывает не всегда. Чтобы пояснить это положение, рассмотрим обычный рабочий стол Windows и командную строку.
> И то и другое — программы, работающие под управлением операционной системы Windows и использующие предоставленные этой системой абстракции, но они предлагают существенно отличающиеся друг от друга пользовательские интерфейсы.

Про какие пользовательские и системные абстракции идет речь? В чем их разница? Еще примеры (написано, что примером системных абстракций является файл, (добавьте еще), а пользовательских - иконки этих файлов (добавьте еще))?

Comment: Системные - это то, как работает. Пользователю пофиг на то, как вы там реализовали свой код, ему важно чтобы было красиво+удобно, что как раз таки и является пользовательской абстракцией (графическим интерфейсом). Я примерно так представляю, имхо